# Incorrect App Icon when searching Start Menu

Tags: c#

I've created a C# console app, set it's `OutputType` to `WinExe` and set it's icon to .ico file using `properties` in Visual Studio.

The app compiles and has a visible .exe icon. I have created a Shortcut to this .exe and placed it in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.  Shortcut has an icon, but when I search in Start Menu, the .exe is with default console app icon. This is what I mean:

[image]

How come the .exe file has the desired icon, it's shortcut in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` as well, but the start menu displays the regular icon you get when you don't specify any icon. What am I missing?

Comment: It's better to be more specific about your IDE and environment details... People who encountered the same issue would help you if you mention VS version...

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the icon cache?  https://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/